# Gulp needs to be updated on macOS Ventura. How to run Gulp on macOS?

Tags: macos, gulp, macos-ventura, yarn-v2

I'm running macOS Ventura v13.4.1. I installed Gulp with brew:

```
brew install gulp
```

and received the message:

```
gulp has been officially discontinued upstream.
It may stop working correctly (or at all) in recent versions of macOS.
```

It was successfully installed

```
==> Moving App 'gulp.app' to '/Applications/gulp.app'
  gulp was successfully installed!
```

However, when I run `yarn dev`  I have an error: `/bin/sh: gulp: command not found`. When I try to pen Gulp from the Application folder I have an error:

> “gulp” needs to be updated. The developer of this app needs to update
> it to work with this version of macOS. Contact the developer for more
> information.

**How can I fix it to run `yarn` command on macOS?**

Comment: You need to find whatever directory contains the `gulp` command and add it to your `PATH` env var. That might be */usr/local/bin*, */opt/bin*, */Applications/gulp.app/Contents/MacOS*, or some other directory. But, obviously if the Gulp app won't run the `gulp` command may also refuse to run. If enough time has elapsed since you installed Gulp the macOS Spotlight service may have updated its index and tell you where the command is located. Otherwise use `find / -name gulp`.